# Negative sentence

Tags: grammar

How can I make this sentence negative 'Either of the boys is present'?

I think it is 'Either of the boys is absent' or 'neither of the boys is present'

Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: The sentence *either of the boys is present* is not at all natural. It's grammatical, at least in the right context, but I can't imagine anybody using it. Neither of your suggestions are negative sentences in the normal sense. (Although I supposed it would depend on what you think a negative sentence is.) A negative sentence would be *the boys are not present* or *one of the boys is not present.*

Comment: pardon my mistake, my first suggestion should have been, Either of the boys is not absent.

is it correct?

Comment: Your second suggestion is correct. "Neither" is called an 'absolute negator', so your example exhibits clausal negation, i.e. it's a negative sentence with non-verbal negation.

Comment: @SajitRahmanRony What I'm saying is you shouldn't be using the words *either* or *neither* if you want to talk about positive or negative sentences in a direct sense that doesn't invite debate. Use *one of* or *a* instead, assuming you don't want to talk about both. And *not absent* is a double negative, which also clouds the concept, because it can be interpreted in different ways.

Comment: Negation can be verbal or non-verbal, cf. "I didn't know either of the boys" vs "I knew neither of them". Your example "Neither of the boys is present" is fine, but there is no verbal negation counterpart, of course.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. The mistake is not in the conclusion, but in the premise -- that one can "make a sentence negative". This is not something that can be done, since there are many kinds of "negative sentences", and no single way to make them. As you have noticed, it's not obvious with this sentence, and that's normal. So start over and ask a question that has an answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler

make it negative in a grammatical way, I hope you got my point.

For example, 'He is a good boy' if I want to make it negative sentence without changing the meaning, it will be 'He is not bad boy'

Hope I have clarified my point

Comment: A useful test is the confirmatory tag one. A positive tag attaches to a negative clause: "Neither of the boys is/are present, are they?" The positive tag shows that the clause is negative.

Comment: @SajitRahmanRony Your example "He is a good boy" is negated as, "He is not a good boy". You only negate either the verb, or the adjective, not both. "He is not a bad boy" is a double negative and means the same thing as "He is a good boy."

Comment: @TylerN: It is clear from Rony's comment above that the "double negative" is exactly what they want. I can't image why anybody would want this, but what they say is "make it [a] negative sentence without changing the meaning".

Comment: @ColinFine Ah, I did not notice that, thanks. To touch on "why anybody would want this," theoretically, "he is a good boy" and "he is not a bad boy," do not have 100% exact meanings. "He is a good boy" makes a statement that he is good, while, "he is not a bad boy" makes no statement about whether he is good or not, it solely states that he is not bad; he could be in a neutral zone of neither good nor bad.

Comment: @TylerN: Of course: Litotes is a very well established figure of speech. But the OP asked for "without changing the meaning"; and that, as you have pointed out, is well-nigh impossible.

Comment: Doesn't "Either of the boys is present." mean "One of the two boys is present"? It's not natural, but if that's its meaning, one negative of the statement, would be the same statement.

Answer (score 1):

The direct negative of "either" is "neither".

However, the meaning of your sentence, "either of the boys is present" is ambiguous.

"Either" is almost always followed by "or"

> Either, conjunction
>
> > used before the first of two  alternatives (the other being introduced by “or”)

However, "either" is **not always** followed by "or", usually when it is not denoting two mutually exclusive alternatives.

For example:

> Either option is okay.
>
> > Meaning, each option is indeed okay; "either" is used instead of "each" to imply that while either could be used, only one will be.

If your sentence means that each boy is present, the correct sentence and its negation would be

> Each of the boys are present / None of the boys are present.

If you sentence means that one of the boys is present, but the other one is not:

> Either this boy, or that boy is present. / Neither this boy, nor that boy is present.